# How to call a script by id using onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

May be obvious but I tried searching and can't figure it out. I am using a third party tool which has a script. The script has an id, but the function within the script has no name. I have a javascript onclick function where all I want to do is call the script *by its id* from an onClick function.

ie. script is

```
<script id="feed" type="text/javascript">(function(){...}())</script>
```

I need to call this script from

```
$('#searchBox').html("<li onClick=\"$(\"#feed\");\">Click to contact us</li>");
```

I tried to call the 'feed' script as above but no luck. In case it matters, the 'feed' script is in the body of the page and #searchBox is an auto-suggest box in a search field on that page. Will appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: What is the third party script?

Comment: The script is a feedback form. I am using standard javascript.

Comment: @tterbeg: `$('#searchBox').html(` isn't "standard javascript".

Comment: What values does that function return? may you should call the method which is returned by the anonymous function. Or that anonymous function might initialize a global object which you should be using.

Comment: @Ramesh: That function can't return anything, but you're right, it could set up some global object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this:

```
$("#searchbox").html("<li onClick=\"eval($(\"#feed\").html())\">Click to contact us</li>")
```

Assuming that the script in #feed executes on its own, and looks something like this: `(function(){...})()`

If, however, the function looks exactly as you posted, `(function(...){})`, this should work:

```
$("#searchbox").html("<li onClick=\"eval($(\"#feed\").html())()\">Click to contact us</li>")
```

Comment: Your first assumption is correct (made the change in the question above). However, using eval(...).html() isn't working :(

Comment: should be eval($("#feed").html())

Comment: sorry - thats what i tried "<li onClick=eval($(\"#feed\").html())>...</li>"

Comment: For some reason, in my JSFiddle test, JSQuery modified the $("#feed") to have a space... $(" #feed") which of course would not work. I instead relied on pure javascript. Proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/S8QHp/1/

Comment: Hmmm... could the problem be that the .js file where the code above goes is in a different file (and folder) than the main html page where 'feed' is located.
<script type="text/javascript" src="sharedElements/searchScripts.js"></script> which is being called by the main.html page in the root folder.

Comment: @tterbeg: It should work as long as `feed` is in the DOM, and the code above is included in the page after `feed` is.

Comment: I guess I need to check with the third party script provider because its still not working... Thanks all though.

Answer (score 2):

You can try making the un-named function into a named function.  By adding a new script tag to the head.

```
$('<script></scr' + 'ipt>', {
    html: 'function feedback(){' + $('#feed').html() + ' }',
    type: 'text/javascript'
}).appendTo('head');
```

Or better yet, by using [`new Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function):

```
var feedback = new Function($('#feed').html());
```

Then use that function in the click handler in the new DOM element.

```
$('#searchBox').html($('<li></li>',{
    text: 'Click to contact us'
}).click(feedback));
```

(I hate using inline JavaScript.)

Comment: +1. I like the `new Function()` option. (Assuming the third-party script can't be changed in any way.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: `new Function` is an implicit `eval`, but that's really the only option here.  But since the script is in a `(function(){...}())`, you can't change it's content (well not in JavaScript anyway, I'm sure you can with some tool).

Comment: Yeah, I meant if the OP couldn't deploy a different version of the script, which would be a much better option than trying to manipulate it in the browser. I realise `new Function` is a sort of `eval`, but to me it seems better to do it once and create an actual function rather than doing `eval` on each click.